# Dagger 2: Inject child class based on logic

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

Using Dagger 2 in my android with MVP pattern, and struggling a little with some concepts.

Let's say I have a presenter `DashboardPresenter`, I am injecting it when I need it in an activity or other presenters, by using:

```
@inject
DashboardPresenter presenter;
```

or in the constructor of other presenters:

```
@inject
public AccountPresenter(DashboardPresenter presenter) {
    //init
}
```

Now I'm not very sure how it works, but I want to do the following:

Let's say I create a `BaseDashboardPresenter` which will be the parent

And I create 2 children for it: `NormalDashboardPresenter` and `ProDashboardPresenter` both extends from it.

When I want to use it in an activity or another presenter, I inject the Base presenter by calling

```
@inject
BaseDashboardPresenter presenter;
```

And I override the `@inject` behavior, to inject one of the children based on a boolean.
So something like this:

```
//in BaseDashboardPresenter 
override inject() {
    if(Utility.checkIfUserIsPro()) {
        inject ProDashboardPresenter();
    } else {
        inject NormalDashboardPresenter();
    } 
}
```

so from my activity I just call the abstract methods in the Base class, and the difference is only which child is injected.

Is this possible?
Happy to provide more clarification if needed.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should add in your module something like this:

```
@Provides
public BaseDashboardPresenter provideDashboardPresenter(OtherPresenter presenter) {
    if (Utility.checkIfUserIsPro()) {
        return new ProDashboardPresenter();
    } else {
        return new NormalDashboardPresenter(presenter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding logic to a `@Provides` method is usually not a good idea and it will get confusing and hard to maintain in case both variants have different dependencies

Comment: Sorry to have omitted this from my question, but  NormalDashboardPresenter takes other presenters and classes as argument and they are all injected. 
`@inject`
`public NormalDashboardPresenter (OtherPresenter) { }`
So I will need to also create instance of OtherPresenter?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Yes you're right. Dagger should only manage injection and shouldn't contains logic.Youssef, you can pass extras presenter as arguments (I've edited my answer)

Comment: @guillaume thank you for the example, I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answer I believe that your modules should not include any logic. That's just not what one would expect.

Also, how would your `@Provides` method look if one variant needs `A`, while the other depends on `B`? Now you need to declare dependencies that you don't need and it just gets more confusing from here on.

---

Instead you should create one module for every option and include the correct module in your component.

```
// module providing pro version
componentBuilder.addPresenterModule(new ProModule());

// or a default one
componentBuilder.addPresenterModule(new DefaultModule());
```

That way wherever you build your component you get to decide what's supposed to be in it. An even more dedicated approach would be to use 2 completely different components where each component uses different modules etc. This might make sense for more complex projects, but in your case it seems that modules would be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but to make sure I understand, you mean I create 2 different modules and at the activity initialization level, I do the check and add the module I want?
If so, what if those modules also have other common dependencies, can I make it as a base module, or will I have to repeat them for each? So if question might seem dumb, I'm just trying to get started in the Dagger world

Comment: @Youssef A component can have more than 1 module, so you can move common dependencies into a third module